# Preserving original time stamp of uploaded file in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage

We are using "Cerebrata Azure Explorer" client utility to upload files into Azure blob storage. Unfortunately original time stamp of files are lost once files are uploaded and uploading time stamp is considering as original time stamp.

Is there any other client utility which will preserve the original time stamp of file even after uploading into blob storage.

Regards
Bibhas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're looking at the "Date modified" property in Cerebrata when you're referring to the original timestamp. Unfortunately this property will always reflect the exact time you upload your file into Blob storage. It's a read-only property so no client utility will be able to modify it. One way to preserve the original timestamp would be to use the client utility to add metadata to your files to hold the original timestamp.